# ($LogIncrease==true) always evaluates to true

Tags: php

I have just installed the latest version of LAMP on Debian 7.0.0.

For some reason, the following code

```
    if ($LogIncrease==true) echo "true" . "<br\>";
    else echo "false" . "<br\>";
    echo "LogIncrease=" . $LogIncrease . "<br\>";
```

returns

```
true
LogIncrease=false
```

when $LogIncrease is actually false and

```
true
LogIncrease=true
```

when $LogIncrease is actually true

When I use

```
    if ($LogIncrease===true) echo "true" . "<br\>";
    else echo "false" . "<br\>";
```

I always get false.  Could someone tell me what is wrong with the way I am using the conditional statement?

Comment: Is `$LogIncrease` actually ever `true` rather than just being true?

Comment: `var_dump($LogIncrease);` --- always use it for debug, not `echo`

Comment: Where did you define `$LoginIncrease`? Also, use var_dump() for debugging.

Comment: Please post the result of var_dump ($LogIncrease); before the if statement.

Comment: According to var_dump($LogIncrease);, $LogIncrease is true 50% of the time.

Comment: @OtagoHarbour lol, your like reading it from an instruction set, what they actually said is to put `var_dump($LogIncrease)` before your `if()` and see what is actually inside `$LogIncrease`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably* happening because `$LogIncrease` is string `"false"` versus the boolean `false`.

[According to the documentation](http://php.net/language.types.boolean), only the following are converted to boolean `false`:

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:
>
> - the boolean `FALSE` itself
> - the **integer** `0` (zero)
> - the **float** `0.0` (zero)
> - the *empty* **string**, and the string `"0"`
> - an **array** with zero elements
> - an **object** with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> - the special type `NULL` (including unset variables)
> - **SimpleXML** objects created from empty tags

The string `"false"` doesn't evaluate to `false`. In other words, `"false" == true`.

Therefore, if `var_dump($LogIncrease)` outputs the following:

```
string(5) "false"
```

It is normal that your condition is evaluated as `true`.

<sup>* Saying probably here because I do not have enough information from your snippet of code to be sure.</sup>

Comment: lol.  Indeed you have identified my problem.  I forgot that I was setting $LogIncrease to a string "true" or "false" instead of to a boolean.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three cases when $LoginIncrease is empty, True, and False respectively:

**Case 1:**

```
$LogIncrease = "";
if ($LogIncrease == True) echo "LogIncrease is True <br/>";
else echo "LogIncrease is False <br/>";
var_dump($LogIncrease);
```

**Output:**

```
LogIncrease is False 
string(0) ""
```

**Case 2:**

```
$LogIncrease = True;
if ($LogIncrease == True) echo "LogIncrease is True <br/>";
else echo "LogIncrease is False <br/>";
var_dump($LogIncrease);
```

**Output**

```
LogIncrease is True 
bool(true)
```

**Case 3:**

```
$LogIncrease = False;
if ($LogIncrease == True) echo "LogIncrease is True <br/>";
else echo "LogIncrease is False <br/>";
var_dump($LogIncrease);
```

**Output**

```
LogIncrease is False 
bool(false)
```

Hope this helps.